# How to get data inside a circle

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, canvas, plot

I am a newbie to Javascript. I am trying to develop web application that will fetch the data and count the child node from the firebase database. Using the count of the node, I am trying to plot the small circles randomly inside a big Circle. Can anyone suggest how to do that. I have attached the code snippet which i have tried. I searched internet for solutions but fails.  Is this is the correct way or am i doing it wrong? Please suggest if it so.

Thanks in advance

**main.html**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: "https://databaseurlcomeshere.firebaseio.com/"
});
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
var refresh = function() {
    dbRef.on("value", function(snap) {
        var totalcount = snapshot.numChildren();

        var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8
        var containerR = 150;
        canvas.width = canvas.height = containerR * 2;
        canvas.style["border-radius"] = containerR + "px";


        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        for (i = 0; i < totalcount; i++) {

            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
            var radius = 10;

            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
            var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, Math.PI * 2, 0, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ",1)";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
    refresh(); 
    button.addEventListener("click", refresh, false); 
    console.log(snap)
})
```

Comment: Some trigonometry will be necessary if you dont want the inner circles to overlap the outer.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with the code @Anonymous? What ain't working?

Comment: @obscure thanks for your time. I am getting the big circle but i am not able to get the firebase data in to it. I want it to randomly plot as small circles by counting the number of children.

Comment: @GetSet Thanks. First i need to get data from the database. My question is how to get firebase data inside a canvas .

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong from your current description. Stack Overflow is an very inefficient interactive debugger, so you will have to do some work to describe to us exactly what is going wrong. For example: if you put a breakpoint on `var totalcount = snapshot.numChildren();` and run the code in a debugger, does it hit that breakpoint? If so, and then step through the code from there, what line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer and its working properly now. When i go through the code i found some flaws in my code.

**First**
`var firebase = require("firebase")`is not needed since i initialize it in second line. Becoz of this it gives me `ReferenceError`

**Second thing**
`dbRef.on("value", function(snap)` is changed to `dbRef.on("value", function(snapshot)` as per @obscure answer

**Third**  `console.log(snap)` is removed.

These are the flaws that i corrected.

And thanks for whoever spend time in this.

Answer (score 0):

This possibly just happens because the variable snapshot you're using inside the `refresh()` function doesn't exist:

```
var totalcount =  snapshot.numChildren();
```

thus **totalcount** stays undefined all the time and your for-loop will never have anything to loop over.

I think you just forgot to name the parameter of your function correctly.

```
dbRef.on("value", function(snap)
```

should be

```
dbRef.on("value", function(snapshot)
```

Comment: i have changed the parameter what you mentioned but still its not showing. Can you please add snippet for ref. Did i do anything wrong in adding database reference?

Comment: Could you add `console.log(totalcount, snapshot);` right after `var totalcount =  snapshot.numChildren();` and check what's written in the developer console?

Comment: its showing this error  ** Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined** but i add correct reference only

Comment: Does the dbRef.on value callback fire at all? Maybe your script stops execution at the `Uncaught ReferenceError` error.